# Nested Data Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do aggregation in nested data

```
 {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_day": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "interval": "day"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "corridors": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "rowData"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "Entrance": {
                            "filter": {
                                "match": {
                                    "rowData.corridors.name": "Office"
                                }
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "SumExit": {
                                    "sum": {
                                        "field": "rowData.corridors.north"
                                    }
                                },
                                "SumIn": {
                                    "sum": {
                                        "field": "rowData.corridors.south"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2019-06-10T00:00:00.000",
                            "lte": "2019-06-18T06:11:18.618Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "account": "5ca195b535374512130add60"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "device._id": "5cae98291b97031201d797a0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

this is an example of data i got

```
{
    "corridor": [
        {
            "name": "Entrance",
            "south": 2,
            "north": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Office",
            "south": 2,
            "north": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

i need to aggregate sum of north and south according to name ex:entrance
but query i write gave me sum of the both entrance and office 
 how can i filter only get sum of entrance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case its `rowData.corridors` that need to a nested field. So, if I assume that your mapping is correct you only need to correct this part of your aggregation :

```
"aggs": {
    "corridors": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "rowData.corridors" <-- HERE
        },
...
```

It seems that the configured nested field in your mapping is rowData. But with this configuration, all corridors are flattened inside the nested "rowData" documents.

I hope my answer is clear enough

Comment: yes, so you need to change your mapping. Is not rowData the must be nested its rowData.corridors

Comment: sorry i didn't get you :(

Comment: Nested data type, allow you to index collections as subdocuments in elasticsearch. It allows you to query those subdocuments independently. In your cases, since you want to do aggregation on corridors but distinguish them by name, you need to make corridors field nested. I recommend you to read this documentation page https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html before going further